# highcharts xaxis navigator not showing

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a few date/value series on a chart, nothing complicated. I would like to have the zooming navigator at the bottom as in here but it doesn't show up on my chart.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: { type: 'spline' },
        title: { text: 'intensity' },
        rangeSelector: { selected: 2},
        xAxis: { type: 'datetime', },
        yAxis: [
            { title: { text: 'Intensity (A)' }, min: 0 },
            { title: { text: 'Nb' }, min: 0, opposite: true },
        ],
        series: [
            { name: 'serie 1', yAxis: 0, visible: false, turboThreshold: 546, marker: {enabled: false}, data: [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09-1, 25, 10, 38, 01, 0), 142.205467], 
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09-1, 25, 10, 43, 01, 0), 142.886567],
                ...]
            },
            { name: 'serie 2', yAxis: 1, visible: false, turboThreshold: 20, marker: {enabled: false}, data: [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09-1, 23, 13, 58, 25, 0), 0.000000], 
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09-1, 23, 13, 58, 26, 0), 1.000000],
                 ... ]
            },
...
```

Just in case this might be the problem, I have roughly 40 series in total and 30000 points in total too.

I have tried to have `navigator: {enabled: true}` and similar things (setting the data serie in the navigator to be the same as my first data serie) but none worked

What should I do ? Do I HAVE to use highstocks ? Their api is more complicated than highcharts and I would prefer to use the latter if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigator is available only in highstock.js file. So you can use this file in combine with you highcharts.

Comment: do you mean just include it ? or do I have to switch completely to highstocks ?

Comment: its pretty sad that there are 2 modules that do almost the same things, with advantages in one or the other. I have 40 series, I don't want them all at the same time. highcharts provides a builtin thing to select the ones I want to show or not for instance. Is there the equivalent on highstock ?